# Does Unity's Social API need some plugins for Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, google-play-services

According to what I've understood, you don't need any plugin to implement Social API's interfaces for iOS because it uses a default implementation from Game Center.

So my question is for Android. Does it need a plugin to implement it or use a default implementation like Google Play Service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware you do need a plugin, luckily Google have stepped up and released an Open-Source plugin :)
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 3):

Amazon also has Unity plugins for GameCircle as well as In-App Purchasing. There are inside the Mobile SDK: https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk

Comment: This plugin doesn't use the Social API in Unity but it does work (on Android).